# Simple Cloud Save to Google Docs

Tags: javascript, cloud, google-api, google-docs

I need a way to save data to a user's Google Docs so that it can be accessed from any computer.

I'm writing a game in javascript/Canvas that will be downloaded as a stored application from the chrome store. All I need to do is save a small text file containing high scores and settings to the user's account, however the authentication process is extremely confusing to me, and I haven't found any javascript sample code that does this.

What is the simplest way to access and modify a user's Google Docs with javascript?

Edit: Is there an easy to way to use Google forms/other API's to save data? Could I use PHP or python with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I've also asked this a while ago.
Google doesn't have released a JavaScript API for Google Docs yet. But since it is a RESTful API, you could implement it by your own.

You can find the protocol documentation here: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

I decided to not do it, because expenditure would be too big for what I wanted to do.

Comment: Do you know if there's an alternative to Google Docs? I edited my post above